# If $G/Z_2 \times ...\times Z_2=S_n$ what is $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $N$ be a normal subgroup in $G$. If $N\cong\mathbb Z_2\times ...\times \mathbb Z_2$ ($n$-times), and if $G/N\cong S_n$. What we can say about $G$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possibilities. Since $N$ is abelian, $G/N$ acts on $N$. Let $C$ be the centraliser of $N$ in $G/N$. This is a normal subgroup of $G/N$, so it must be either $1$, $A_n$ or $S_n$.

If $C=S_n$ (that is, if $N$ is central in $G$), then we have a central extension and the theory of Schur multipliers will be useful. One possibility is  that  $N$ splits and $G\cong S_n\times N$ but there are others. The case $C=A_n$ is somewhat similar.

Finally, if $C=1$, then $S_n$ acts faithfully on $N$ and you are asking about embedding $S_n$ in $GL(n,2)$. There is one obvious option, where you simply permute the coordinate, in which case $G$ is the wreath product $\mathbb{Z}_2\wr S_n$, but there are others. For example, if $n=3$, we can have $G=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times S_4$. ($S_4$ has a normal subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$.)